# Aggregating data per minute on multiple fields

Tags: python, pandas

I have four columns in my dataset where one of columns is timestamp in epoch which I converted to datetime using pd.to_datetime and I would like to get the count of each group per minute

The dataset is something like this

```py
timestamp col2 col3 col4
1555127370.734 x a  p
1555127370.980 y b  q
1555127371.376 z c  r
1555127371.430 x a  p
1555127371.313 w g  t
1555127371.748 z h  u
```

So i need them to be grouped by per minute per col2 per col3 per col4 and the count of that group.

Is there a way to do this pandas?

**EDIT**
The output should look like this

```
1555127340 x a p 2
1555127340 y b q 1
1555127340 z c r 1
1555127340 w g t 1
1555127340 z h u 1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You want to get the count of each group?

Comment: @U9-Forward, yes. and that group should be aggregated per minute

Comment: And see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.size.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')

df = df.resample('min', on='timestamp').size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
            timestamp  count
0 2019-04-13 03:49:00      6
```

Alternative is [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='min', key='timestamp')).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Another approach id remove seconds by [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and pass to `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.floor('min')).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
            timestamp  count
0 2019-04-13 03:49:00      6
```

---

If need grouping with multiple columns use `list`:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')
df1 = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='min', key='timestamp'), 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'],sort=False)
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
            timestamp col2 col3 col4  count
0 2019-04-13 03:49:00    x    a    p      2
1 2019-04-13 03:49:00    y    b    q      1
2 2019-04-13 03:49:00    z    c    r      1
3 2019-04-13 03:49:00    w    g    t      1
4 2019-04-13 03:49:00    z    h    u      1
```

Comment: Does this group-by each column as well? and is it possible to display the other columns as well?

Comment: @Abhishek - I think yes, can you add expected output DataFrame to your sample data?

Comment: @Abhishek - Thank you, check last paragraph.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I have updated my question with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
print(df.groupby(df['timestamp'].map(lambda x: x.minute)).count())
```

Comment: I just get rows likes -
`
timestamp
0               41303 41303 41303 41303
`
I need something like
t x a q 2